# Dependency issues with rpmfusion repos

Tags: fedora, rpm, yum, fedora20, fedora-21

I recently upgraded from fedora 20 to fedora 21. I am facing dependency issues when trying to install or update:

```
$ sudo yum -y upgrade
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vlc.x86_64 0:2.2.1-2.fc21 will be updated
---> Package vlc.x86_64 0:2.2.1-3.fc22 will be an update
---> Package vlc-core.x86_64 0:2.2.1-2.fc21 will be updated
---> Package vlc-core.x86_64 0:2.2.1-3.fc22 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libx265.so.25()(64bit) for package: vlc-core-2.2.1-3.fc22.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liblua-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: vlc-core-2.2.1-3.fc22.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreerdp.so.1.2()(64bit) for package: vlc-core-2.2.1-3.fc22.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreerdp-server.so.1.2()(64bit) for package: vlc-core-2.2.1-3.fc22.x86_64
---> Package x264-libs.x86_64 0:0.142-11.20141221git6a301b6.fc21 will be updated
---> Package x264-libs.x86_64 0:0.142-11.20141221git6a301b6.fc22 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.2.1-3.fc22.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libfreerdp-server.so.1.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.4.9-1.fc22.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libcdio_paranoia.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.2.1-3.fc22.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: liblua-5.3.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.4.9-1.fc22.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libcdio_cdda.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.2.1-3.fc22.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libx265.so.25()(64bit)
           Available: x265-libs-1.2-5.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free)
               libx265.so.25()(64bit)
           Available: x265-libs-1.2-6.fc22.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
               libx265.so.25()(64bit)
           Installed: x265-libs-1.6-1.fc21.x86_64 (@rpmfusion-free-updates)
              ~libx265.so.51()(64bit)

 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried disabling/enabling some repos, trying to update, trying to remove some of the libraries listed above, but all in vain.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit in my case was rpmfusion. I had different versions of rpmfusion-free and rpmfusion-nonfree. One of them was 21 and other was 22. So removing and installing the correct versions as follows solved the issue:

*`sudo yum remove rpmfusion-free-release rpmfusion-nonfree-release`*

```
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rpmfusion-free-release.noarch 0:22-0.1 will be erased
---> Package rpmfusion-nonfree-release.noarch 0:21-1 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

======================================================================================================================================
 Package                                  Arch                  Version                  Repository                              Size
======================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 rpmfusion-free-release                   noarch                22-0.1                   @rpmfusion-free-rawhide                9.7 k
 rpmfusion-nonfree-release                noarch                21-1                     installed                              9.9 k

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================
Remove  2 Packages

Installed size: 20 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction (shutdown inhibited)
  Erasing    : rpmfusion-nonfree-release-21-1.noarch                                                                              1/2 
  Erasing    : rpmfusion-free-release-22-0.1.noarch                                                                               2/2 
warning: /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo saved as /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo.rpmsave
  Verifying  : rpmfusion-nonfree-release-21-1.noarch                                                                              1/2 
  Verifying  : rpmfusion-free-release-22-0.1.noarch                                                                               2/2 

Removed:
  rpmfusion-free-release.noarch 0:22-0.1                            rpmfusion-nonfree-release.noarch 0:21-1                           

Complete!
```

*`su -c 'yum localinstall http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm'`*

```
Password: 
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks
rpmfusion-free-release-21.noarch.rpm                                                                           |  19 kB  00:00:00     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-d5sSL9/rpmfusion-free-release-21.noarch.rpm: rpmfusion-free-release-21-1.noarch
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-d5sSL9/rpmfusion-free-release-21.noarch.rpm to be installed
rpmfusion-nonfree-release-21.noarch.rpm                                                                        |  19 kB  00:00:00     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-d5sSL9/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-21.noarch.rpm: rpmfusion-nonfree-release-21-1.noarch
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-d5sSL9/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-21.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rpmfusion-free-release.noarch 0:21-1 will be installed
---> Package rpmfusion-nonfree-release.noarch 0:21-1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

======================================================================================================================================
 Package                                Arch                Version           Repository                                         Size
======================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 rpmfusion-free-release                 noarch              21-1              /rpmfusion-free-release-21.noarch                 9.7 k
 rpmfusion-nonfree-release              noarch              21-1              /rpmfusion-nonfree-release-21.noarch              9.9 k

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================
Install  2 Packages

Total size: 20 k
Installed size: 20 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction (shutdown inhibited)
  Installing : rpmfusion-free-release-21-1.noarch                                                                                 1/2 
  Installing : rpmfusion-nonfree-release-21-1.noarch                                                                              2/2 
  Verifying  : rpmfusion-nonfree-release-21-1.noarch                                                                              1/2 
  Verifying  : rpmfusion-free-release-21-1.noarch                                                                                 2/2 

Installed:
  rpmfusion-free-release.noarch 0:21-1                             rpmfusion-nonfree-release.noarch 0:21-1                            

Complete!
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the **rpmfusion-free-rawhide** repo, it's for yet unreleased Fedora 22. That should solve all your problems.